# How to effectively process HashMap in order described by list?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, java-stream

This is my problem:
I have a list of event names in chronological order, example:

```
ArrayList<String> eventsOrder = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("event1", "event2", "event3", "event4", "event5"));
```

I have HashMap of data about events, where key is events name, example:

```
HashMap<String, String> eventsData = new HashMap<>();
    eventsData.put("event2", "data2");
    eventsData.put("event1", "data1");
    eventsData.put("event3", "data3");
```

I also have a method that merges Data from 2 events into 1:

```
public String merge(String previousEventsData, String nextEventsData);
```

I need to merge all of events' data into one object **in chronological order**. So in this case it would be something like this:

```
merge(merge("data1", "data2"),"data3");
```

This how I solve it now:

Firstly, this HashMap may or may not contain data about all of the events so i filter names of the ones that are available:

```
ArrayList<String> eventsToProcess = eventsOrder.stream()
                .filter(eventName -> eventsData.containsKey(eventName))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Then I use this ugly algorithm to merge events' data in chronological order:

```
    String finalData = "";

    int eventsCount = namesToProcess.size();

    finalData = eventsData.get(namesToProcess.get(0));
    if(eventsCount > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < eventsCount; i++){
            finalData = merge(finalData, eventsData.get(namesToProcess.get(i)));
        }

    }
```

Not very elegant and readable, right?

Question:
How would I do same processing with Java streams or a recursive function?

Comment: I think you want to use the `Stream.reduce(merge)` function. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

Comment: More options: a) use [NavigableMap.subMap(from, to).values()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap(K,boolean,K,boolean)) b) There are `Map`s allowing iteration in insertion order, e.g. [`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should be equivalent, using [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```java
eventsOrder.stream()          // "event1", "event2", "event3", "event4", "event5"
    .map(eventsData::get)     // "data1", "data2", "data3", null, null
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // "data1", "data2", "data3"
    .reduce(YourClass::merge) // merge(merge("data1", "data2"), "data3")
    .get()                    // gets the result from the Optional
```

The [`Optional.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) method throws `NoSuchElementException` if there are no events with data; your original code's `namesToProcess.get(0)` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in that case. That should be the only difference in behaviour, assuming your `eventsData` map doesn't have any `null` values.

Comment: I will never suggest someone to use `.get()` ,My suggestion when you already using `reduce()` then why not return something as identity??

Comment: @VishwaRatna Not every binary operation has an identity, and the OP's `merge` method is not specified as having one. Calling `.get()` without a guard is appropriate when the code is expected to always produce a result, and the absence of a result indicates a coding error; in that case, you want an error message. Given that the OP's code fails in the same way in that case, I chose to answer in a way which preserves the failure condition, but you will notice that I pointed out the failure condition in my answer in case the OP wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Starting with Java 10, you can use `orElseThrow()` which does the same as `get()`, but is explicit about the behavior when no matching element was there.